# How to prevent from notifying user on the screen about new change in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

This is how I prepare subscription:

```
class func saveSubscriptions() {

    let options: CKSubscriptionOptions = [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion]
    let serviceSubscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Service", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), options: options)
    
    let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "s"
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = false

    serviceSubscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    CloudContainer.publicCloudDatabase.save(serviceSubscription) { _, _ in }
}
```

and notification appears on the screen permanently.

[image]

I really do not want this here. Is there a way to deliver the notification if app is active but to not display anything while the app is not running or is in the foreground mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup the notification info properly. Don't set `alertLocalizationKey`. `shouldSendContentAvailable` should be set to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, this will not show banner for notification

```
let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.shouldBadge = false
notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo
```